Google Calendar API Events watch
I've used the Google Calendar API Events watch to create (what I assume should be) a webhook subscription to track updates to Calendar Events for a specific calendar.
The subscription has been created and webhooks are thrown when an Event on the nominated Calendar is created/updated/deleted.
However, the problem I have is that the webhook body which is sent in response to Calendar Event CRUD looks like this:
{
"value": "IMTBuffer(0, binary, da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709): "
}

Can anyone suggest what's happened here?
NOTE: The Calendar is not mine, but I am designated a Calendar Editor and it appears in my Calendar list and I can query events from that Calendar using Calendar API Events:list
Watch Event creation looked like this:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/name@domain.co.uk/events/watch
{
    "id": "{randomUUID}",
    "type": "web_hook",
    "address": "https://hook.eu1.make.com/{idremoved}",
     "params": {
           "ttl": "2592000" }
}

Response 200, as follows;
{
    "kind": "api#channel",
    "id": "{UUID as above}",
    "resourceId": "{IDremoved}",
    "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/name@domain.co.uk/events?alt=json&eventTypes=default",
    "expiration": "1720169269000"
}


Can you add more details and the error you are encountering?

George, thanks. There is no error.
The Google Events Watch API fires as expected but the data it sends is invalid.
Google does not document what data should be sent, but I would expect it would be the uid of the event which has changed.
But the data sent is this
{
"value": "IMTBuffer(0, binary, da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709): "
}
